# Why isn't the jQuery .done() not recognizing an external function

Tags: jquery, deferred

I have something like this:

```
  //works fine
  $.ajax("info.txt")
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log("works");
    })
```

I also have something like this:

```
  //throws an error, stating CheckIt() inside the .done() is not a function
  $.ajax("info.txt")
    .done(function(data) {
      CheckIt(data);
    });

  function CheckIt(da) {
    console.log("it works");
  }
```

Why am I receiving the error and how can I circumvent the error allowing me to use other functions.

Comment: Does the same happen if you put the function declaration before the `$.ajax`?

Comment: Haven't tried but let me try it out. Thanks - tried it and it's the same error.

Comment: When do you call this code, directly or in a Jquery Ready?

Comment: directly... would it matter? I didn't think you needed it to be in jquery ready since it's an ajax call?

Comment: it is working without error: https://jsfiddle.net/Patika72/xpvt214o/899848/   may be you have checkit function declared twice?

Comment: Hmmmmm weird it wasn't working before :/... it's working now as per @jrummel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your ajax request is failing. If you replace done with always, it will always be called, even if the request fails.

```js
$.ajax("https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random")
  .always(function(data) {
    CheckIt(data);
  });

function CheckIt(da) {
  alert("it works");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it to call always... it's only if successful.

Comment: Is your request successful?

Comment: Is there any way to check if it's completed via done.... and check the true./false in always